# How to add a Hodrick-Prescott filtered trend on a pandas groupby?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm currently stuck trying to get the [Hodrick-Prescott](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.filters.hp_filter.hpfilter.html) trend from different groups within a monthly dataset. Here's a replica of the dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)),
                  columns=list('abcd'))

df['date'] = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', 
                           periods=100, freq='M')

df['id'] = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3', 'Group 4'] * 25

df.rename({'a': 'target'}, axis=1, inplace=True)


final_df = df.groupby('id', 
                      group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda x: x.sort_values('date'))
```

The Dataset looks like this:

```
    target  b   c   d   date    id
0   28  45  17  46  2018-01-31  Group 1
4   58  23  34  76  2018-05-31  Group 1
8   30  98  91  79  2018-09-30  Group 1
12  15  23  25  96  2019-01-31  Group 1
16  67  45  41  38  2019-05-31  Group 1
20  28  40  36  38  2019-09-30  Group 1
24  8   95  28  86  2020-01-31  Group 1
28  14  53  58  75  2020-05-31  Group 1
32  46  3   26  61  2020-09-30  Group 1
36  50  71  80  34  2021-01-31  Group 1
40  78  38  97  75  2021-05-31  Group 1
44  15  74  83  25  2021-09-30  Group 1
48  27  43  18  84  2022-01-31  Group 1
52  84  38  11  24  2022-05-31  Group 1
56  23  29  81  22  2022-09-30  Group 1
60  87  56  92  65  2023-01-31  Group 1
64  24  99  55  86  2023-05-31  Group 1
68  16  68  36  63  2023-09-30  Group 1
72  43  29  80  44  2024-01-31  Group 1
76  0   48  35  49  2024-05-31  Group 1
80  17  50  51  51  2024-09-30  Group 1
84  17  16  40  87  2025-01-31  Group 1
88  98  13  70  27  2025-05-31  Group 1
92  21  30  96  87  2025-09-30  Group 1
96  19  35  32  47  2026-01-31  Group 1
1   21  45  34  61  2018-02-28  Group 2
5   35  15  95  11  2018-06-30  Group 2
9   3   31  94  25  2018-10-31  Group 2
13  65  89  1   7   2019-02-28  Group 2
17  77  41  12  58  2019-06-30  Group 2
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
82  32  99  54  27  2024-11-30  Group 3
86  67  5   71  44  2025-03-31  Group 3
90  79  94  34  53  2025-07-31  Group 3
94  4   60  37  85  2025-11-30  Group 3
98  20  16  32  97  2026-03-31  Group 3
3   70  63  94  98  2018-04-30  Group 4
7   2   13  14  5   2018-08-31  Group 4
11  49  44  20  27  2018-12-31  Group 4
15  11  60  39  10  2019-04-30  Group 4
19  22  96  48  5   2019-08-31  Group 4
23  23  22  30  8   2019-12-31  Group 4
27  39  11  58  89  2020-04-30  Group 4
31  61  72  68  78  2020-08-31  Group 4
35  29  20  7   30  2020-12-31  Group 4
39  53  20  32  98  2021-04-30  Group 4
43  97  31  60  74  2021-08-31  Group 4
47  46  65  15  93  2021-12-31  Group 4
51  31  24  5   75  2022-04-30  Group 4
55  42  59  87  68  2022-08-31  Group 4
59  75  50  62  60  2022-12-31  Group 4
63  5   24  15  83  2023-04-30  Group 4
67  77  12  81  44  2023-08-31  Group 4
71  74  15  11  90  2023-12-31  Group 4
75  34  0   19  81  2024-04-30  Group 4
79  2   26  36  98  2024-08-31  Group 4
83  45  66  9   23  2024-12-31  Group 4
87  74  67  35  98  2025-04-30  Group 4
91  69  78  46  7   2025-08-31  Group 4
95  66  77  91  41  2025-12-31  Group 4
99  66  11  96  91  2026-04-30  Group 4
```

Here's my current approach:

```
groups = final_df.groupby('id')

group_keys = list(groups.groups.keys())

bs = pd.DataFrame()

for key in group_keys:

    g = groups.get_group(key)

    target = g['target']

    cycle, trend = sm.tsa.filters.hpfilter(target, lamb=129600)

    g['hp_trend'] = trend

    bs.append(g)
```

My goal is to simply generate the trend from HP-Filter for each group and append it to that group as a column such that each group will have its own trend based on the target field specified.

Currently, the `bs` dataframe only returns the empty dataframe that it started with. How can I get the result that I need?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
groups = final_df.groupby('id')

group_keys = list(groups.groups.keys())

bs = pd.DataFrame()

for key in group_keys:

    g = groups.get_group(key).copy()
    target = g['target']

    cycle, trend = sm.tsa.filters.hpfilter(target, lamb=129600)

    g['hp_trend'] = trend
    bs = bs.append(g)

bs
```

Comment: Wow! So the approach was working just that I needed to make a copy?

Comment: @Mysterio the problem was with append. You were not updating the data frame

Comment: OMG! Now I feel so stupid. I have been scratching my head for the past 5 hours! How have I not caught that :(

Comment: @Mysterio Happens to the best of us ;)